# Implementing FTP GitHub Action upload file by file

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I would like to implement a function with GitHub Actions that will upload to a website any file that is pushed to the repository. My problem is that `on: push` is triggered whenever anything changes and it doesn't tell you what actually was pushed, so I'm forced to upload via FTP the entire repository. Is there a way to know which file(s) were pushed?

```
name: Deploy file by file via FTP
on: push
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: push-ftp
      uses: myuser/my-action@releases/v1
      with:
        url: "ftp://ftp.mywebsite.com/"
        files: ${ LIST_OF_FILES } // <-- this is the part I'm missing 
        user: ${{ secrets.FTP_USER }}
        password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PWD }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~
```

gives you the list of files changed in the last commit.